What is the nested if equivalent in PySpark?
I am a beginner to pySpark and I am working on enriching a dataframe which performs lookups from 2 other dataframes, what I want to achieve is:
This is an example:



incoming_path
outgoing_path
event_direction
Other_fields




A
NA
I
Lookup with incoming_path and enrich dataframe


NA
B
O
Lookup with outgoing_path and enrich dataframe


C
D
TI(Consider once for incoming_node for enriching and duplicate the complete record below)



C
D
TO(Consider the duplicated record as outgoing_node for enriching dataframe)




What I am trying to achieve here is if both incoming_path and outgoing_path are not null values then we first duplicate the entire current record and then in event_direction for the first record lit(TI) and perform all the lookups and enriching according to incoming_path and then in the duplicated record lit(TO) and perform all the lookups and enriching according to outgoing_path
My current code looks like this,
# EVENT_DIRECTION
table1_parsed_df = table1_parsed_df.withColumn('event_direction', 
                   when((col("incoming_path") != 'NA') & (col("outgoing_path") != 'NA'), lit("T"))
                   .when(col("incoming_path") != 'NA', lit("I"))
                   .when(col("outgoing_path") != 'NA', lit("O"))
                   .otherwise(lit("E")))

I also wrote a function to split the records into two:
def process_split_logic(df):
    both_present = df.filter((col("incoming_node") != 'NA') & (col("outgoing_node") != 'NA'))
    duplicated_records = both_present.select(
        lit('NA').alias("incoming_node"),
        col("outgoing_node").alias("outgoing_node"),
        *[col(c) for c in df.columns if c not in ["incoming_node", "outgoing_node"]]
    )
    original_records = df.withColumn(
        "outgoing_node",
        when((col("incoming_node") != 'NA') & (col("outgoing_node") != 'NA'), lit('NA')).otherwise(col("outgoing_node"))
    )
    combined_df = original_records.union(duplicated_records)
    return combined_df

With this code I am currently able to split the records into two and perform the lookups, but I don't know how to achieve the conditional if nesting, where, if both incoming_path and outgoing_path are Not NA I want to enter the conditional clause of to write TI for one record and TO for one record as well as perform those lookups. I am currently moving ahead with making one field 'NA' and keeping the other as it is, so the lookups are performed as expected and not ambiguous, as according to my current code, if incoming_path is found first it'll enrich the values based on that directly and not even move to outgoing_path code

You can try the code below:
df=df.withColumn("event_direction",when(((col("incoming_path").isNotNull()) & (col("outgoing_path").isNotNull())),array(lit("TI"),lit("TO")))\
                                  .when(col("incoming_path").isNotNull(),array(lit("I")))\
                                  .when(col("outgoing_path").isNotNull(),array(lit("O"))))

df=df.withColumn("event_direction",explode(col("event_direction")))
df.show()

It will create output like below. You can then use this for lookups
|incoming_path|outgoing_path|event_direction|        Other_fields|
+-------------+-------------+---------------+--------------------+
|            A|         NULL|              I|Lookup with incom...|
|         NULL|            B|              O|Lookup with outgo...|
|            C|            D|             TI|                NULL|
|            C|            D|             TO|                NULL|
+-------------+-------------+---------------+--------------------+


try also explode_outer if your column contain nulls and you wanna preserve the rows

Thanks, I also wanted to ask, that according my current logic, for lookups and enrichments I use spark sql, based on that, I first check if the incoming_path field is not null I look it up in another table and enrich data from it, and vice versa for outgoing_path, how do I modify the logic such that, it only performs lookup for incoming_path for the first 'TI' Event direction and then lookup for outgoing_path in the second record, that is 'TO' Event direction?
